# SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence Python

Tags: python

Подскажите где тут ошибка?? Это бот для поиска музыки.

```
def is_youtube_url(url):
    youtube_regex = (
        r'(https?://)?(www\.)?'
        '(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
        '(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')
    youtube_match = re.match(youtube_regex, url)
    return bool(youtube_match)


C:\Users\COMP\PycharmProjects\REFinderMusic\REFinder-Music\refinderbot.py:200: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
  '(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
C:\Users\COMP\PycharmProjects\REFinderMusic\REFinder-Music\refinderbot.py:201: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\?'
  '(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')
```

Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
def is_youtube_url(url):
    youtube_regex = (
        r'(https?://)?(www\.)?'
        r'(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
        r'(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')
    youtube_match = re.match(youtube_regex, url)
    return bool(youtube_match)
```